# golang preflight request error

Tags: go, cors, mux

I have set up my Go backend using `gorilla/mux` and `rs/cors`. When I try to send a request including a custom header (`Bearer`) it fails.

My server setup looks like this:

```
     router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.HandleFunc("/users", GetUsers).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/", GetUsers).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/tweets", GetTweets).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/login", Login).Methods("POST")
router.HandleFunc("/profile/tweets", ProfileTweets).Methods("GET")

c := cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
    AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "PATCH"},
    AllowedHeaders: []string{"Bearer", "Content_Type"},})

handler := c.Handler(router)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler))
```

I have tried various other solutions (such as adding `OPTIONS` in the `Methods` call.
The endpoint for which I am trying to pass the `Bearer` token is the `/profile/tweets` endpoint.

I'm unsure how to continue with `gorilla/mux` and `rs/cors` in terms of adding the preflight request.

The actual error that I get:

> Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/profile/tweets. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it `Content-Type` instead of `Content_Type`?

Comment: @FrançoisP. That might have been it.. I've just solved it actually, I also need to add `OptionsPassthrough`

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: @FrançoisP. Thank you for the comment though! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just solved the problem. I had a typo in the `AllowedHeaders` as pointed out by @Francois P.

In addition, I had to add `OptionsPassthrough` and the `OPTIONS` method, like so:

```
     router.HandleFunc("/profile/tweets", ProfileTweets).Methods("GET","OPTIONS")

c := cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedMethods: []string{"GET","POST", "OPTIONS"},
    AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    AllowedHeaders: []string{"Content-Type","Bearer","Bearer ","content-type","Origin","Accept"},
    OptionsPassthrough: true,
})
```

Comment: @PieOhPah I would but I have to wait some time ;-)